# como comparar un datos repetidos en un arreglo usando for of en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, array

Estoy atorado en la codificación de un programa que compara el contenido de un array usando el "for of", es la primera ves que lo veo y no logro detectar mi error.
Este es mi codigo.
Espero me puedan ayudar

```
const nombres = [
                "Jorge", "María", 'Jose', 'Ana', 'Luis', 'Ana', 'José', 'Jose', 'Sergio', 'Luis', 'Hugo', 'Paco', 'Luis', 'María', 'Paco'
                ];
console.log(nombres)
                console.log(nombres.length)
                for(var i=0,len=nombres.length;i<len;i++){
                    var cont=nombres[i]
                    console.log(cont)
                    for(var x=0;x<nombres.length;x++){
                        if(cont!==nombres[i]){
                        console.log("Rep: "+cont)
                         }
                     }
                }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado deseado y cuál es el que estás obteniendo?

Comment: quiero conocer los nombres que se repiten, usando for of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es utilizar la función `includes()` para saber si este elemento ya está en un arreglo

```
const nombres = [
                "Jorge", "María", 'Jose', 'Ana', 'Luis', 'Ana', 'José', 'Jose', 'Sergio', 'Luis', 'Hugo', 'Paco', 'Luis', 'María', 'Paco'
                ];
//nuevo arreglo donde irán los nombres NO repetidos 
let todos = []                

//console.log(nombres.length)
for(var i=0,len=nombres.length;i<len;i++){
    var cont=nombres[i]
    if(todos.includes(cont)){
        console.log("rep:"+cont)
    }else{
        //si no esta repetido lo agregamos al arreglo
        //esto para saber que este nombre ya existe 
        todos.push(cont)
    }
}
```